# haskell basecase in balanced-fold

Tags: haskell

There are different kinds of folds in Haskell like `foldl` and `foldr`.
I read about the following balanced-fold:

```
balanced_fold::(e->e->e)->e->[e]->e
balanced_fold _ b [] =b
balanced_fold f b l@(_:_:_)=
   let 
      len= length l
      (half1,half2)=
        divide_list (div len 2) l
      value1=balanced_fold f b half1
      value2=balanced_fold f b half2
   in 
      f value1 value2
divide_list :: Int-> [a]->([a],[a])
divide_list _ [] =([],[])
divide_list n (x:xs)
     | n==0 =([],x:xs)
     | otherwise =
         let (half1,half2)=
             divide_list (n-1) xs
         in 
             (x:half1, half2)
```

From the definition, when the list just contains one element `[x]` the output will be `x`.

My question is: is it right that, when a list just contains one element, we don't need to use the base value to deal with this element?

As we know, `foldr` and `foldl` do use the base value to deal with the element in the list even there is just one.

```
foldl::(v->e->v)->v->[e]->v
foldl _ base [] =base
foldl f base (x:xs)=
     let newbase =f base x in
     foldl f newbase xs
```

Comment: sorry, but what is the question?

Comment: i wwant to know if the balanced-fold use the base value to deal with the element in the list(if there is just one element in the list)?

Comment: @Carsten There is one, but it's hidden. I'll reformat the text.

Comment: ok sorry - the problem right now is, that your balanced fold will not work at because of the pattern `(_:_:_)` - for example there is no case for a list with just one element

Comment: When there is just one element in the list, balanced_fold does not work at all because there is no pattern match for (x:[]) You get "Non-exhaustive patterns in function balanced_fold". In fact it only works on an empty list. Also foldr and foldl always use the base case, even if there is just one element in the list. This is how the iteration ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this answers your question:

First let's fix your function:

```
balanced_fold :: (e -> e -> e) -> e -> [e] -> e
balanced_fold _ b []  = b
balanced_fold f b [a] = f b a
balanced_fold f b l =
   let len= length l
       (half1,half2)= divide_list (div len 2) l
       value1=balanced_fold f b half1
       value2=balanced_fold f b half2
   in f value1 value2
```

as you can see I added a case that deals with lists of lenght 1 (the missing piece) - also I hope you now see where your *base-case*  is

The problem with what you had was, that it had no matching cases for lists with just one element - and even if you would remove the `(_:_:_)` (which you don't really need) you would end up in situations where `divide_list` always give you something like `([],[x])` and the `[x]` would recurse in the same case - that's why you need the extra case to deal with exactly this situation.

Here is a quick test-session to see if it works:

```
λ> balanced_fold (+) 0 []
0
λ> balanced_fold (+) 0 [1]
1
λ> balanced_fold (+) 0 [1..4]
10
λ> balanced_fold (+) 0 [1..5]
15
```

seems to be ok I think

---

### maybe nice to know

notice how this all only works when your operation is *associative* and if you have some kind of *base*/*neutral* element (to this operation).

There is already a class [`Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Monoid) for all this and so you could write this too:

```
import Data.Monoid

balanced_fold :: Monoid e => [e] -> e
balanced_fold []  = mempty
balanced_fold [a] = a
balanced_fold l =
   let len           = length l
       (half1,half2) = divide_list (div len 2) l
       value1        = balanced_fold half1
       value2        = balanced_fold half2
   in value1 `mappend ` value2
```

See it's just

- `f` is now `mappend`
- `b` is just `mempty`

Now it's a bit ugly to apply for the example:

```
λ> balanced_fold (map Sum [1..4])
Sum {getSum = 10}
```

but that's just because there is more than one monoid possible for numbers.